# Generate notification in slack channel whenever there is a change in a table or schema in RDS

Tags: postgresql, triggers, amazon-rds, slack

I have a PostgreSQL DB instance in my RDS. There are frequent changes happening in this instance. Like new tables/schemas gets added or a table name is changed or a new column is added to an existing table or a column name is changed of an existing table. I want to be notified in slack whenever there is such a change/update.

I did a lot of RnD but couldn't find any. We can create SNS topics but they only capture DB instance level events like an instance is down, or an instance is created or deleted and stuff like that but nothing on schema or table level.

I have one approach in mind but that is not a very clean approach. My idea is to write a trigger on the information_schema.columns that contains the list of the schema's, tables, their column names and types. And whenever there is a change in any of the records in this table, the trigger will be triggered. But i can't figure out how to get the trigger to notify in my slack channel.

Comment: Check the documentation on [Event Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/event-trigger-definition.html).

Comment: Sounds like you actually want an AUDIT plugin, which is then configured to record DDL changes. Check https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md#pgauditlog and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.13x for details.

Comment: @Cninroh thanks foe the response, the pgaudit is used for logging purposes, and the logs is stored locally, I can't create a trigger out of it that will send notifications on slack

Comment: have you tried: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/